# AIR Install: Can it overwrite previous installation?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have an AIR EXE and I package it in an install file. When it installs it fails because a previous installation of the app is already there. Can't it act like every other piece of software out there and just overwrite it?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you might try is changing the version number to a latter version if haven't already done so. That way it will see it as a update to the software and not a over write to the software. Just a guess with out seeing any code.

Comment: Where do you change version number? I'm exporting release build from FlashBuilder.

Comment: If you go to the project .xml file there is one field called <versionNumber> by default it will have 0.0.0 in it you should change that to 0.0.1 so it thinks it a new version of the number. The xml file is under your src folder. if you still can't find it let me know and ill post staff on my blog and add a link that way i can put up photos. (I'm guess you creating a desktop application)